# Missing desktop icons with Nemo on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nautilus, 16.04, nemo, amd-graphics

I recently upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. On my computer I used to replace Nautilus with Nemo. Since Ubuntu was upgraded, it looks like Nemo is no more able to handle the desktop display. Instead of displaying the desktop background and the icons, a black blank screen is displayed (the lateral navigation bar is still present and applications open the right way).

It seems Nemo is no more able to handle the desktop the right way, at least on this computer. I manage to have some ghosts displays when moving a application window over the desktop. Maybe a display driver issue (AMD ?)

Answer (score 4):

Note, from http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/nemo-with-unity-patches-available-for.html

> Nemo 2.8.6 is available in the official Ubuntu 16.04 repositories
>   however, it can't be used to draw the desktop under Unity and it comes
>   with Cinnamon dependencies.

A patched version is available here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html

Answer (score 3):

In order to temporary fix this issue, I restored Nautilus as the default desktop manager:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

To switch back to Nemo:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

Answer (score 0):

Then open Startup Applications, click *Add*. Use any name you wish, use this as the command

```
nemo-desktop
```

For testing you can type the below command in terminal:

```
 nemo-desktop
```

It worked for me.
For ease you could add this to your startup applications
command as `nemo-desktop`.